# Fetch MySQL Data with fitting String-End

Tags: mysql, string, fetch

Is is somehow possible, to fetch every String of a Table, which ends with the letters "ly"?

Would this work: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE word LIKE %ly`;

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant: "to fetch every record of a table with matching string expression for a specific field", then try (as you suggested):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myField LIKE '%ly';
```

Just put your search string into single quotes.